# ls and chmod not working on a nfs mounted file

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod, nfs, ls

I mounted a directory using nfs. I am able to cd into the mounted directory and able to list the
one file in the directory. But when I try a `ls -li` on the file, it keeps failing with
`ls: rst_dst/testnew1: Permission denied`.

I tried to chmod the file but it keeps failing with `chmod: failed to get attributes of 'rst_dst/testnew1': Permission denied`. Even the stat command keeps failing with 'Unable to stat the file'.
I tried a sudo ls/chmod but it fails with the same errors.

I am able to chmod the file on the actual machine hosting the directory. But unable to read/write/modidy the permissions through the mounted directory.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

On hosting machine check file **/etc/exports** which permissions you allow.

On guest machine check your **mount command** or **line in /etc/fstab** with which permissions you are mounting it.